# Android crash - Input dispatching timed out - Where is it coming from?

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog

On the Android developer console I can see several reports like this for my app:

```
Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago. Wait queue length: 18. Wait queue head age: 20504.4ms.)
```

They all happen exclusively on 64 bit devices. But the stack trace does not point me to any particular point in my code so I don't know where to start looking for this problem since I can not reproduce it on my test devices.

This is the stack trace as shown on the developer console:

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x768f0760 self=0x7ee92c7a00
  | sysTid=9087 nice=-4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7eedc61a98
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=3703 stm=1083 core=4 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7fd240b000-0x7fd240d000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 000000000006a5f4  /system/lib64/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+8)
  #01  pc 000000000001e31c  /system/lib64/libc.so (epoll_pwait+64)
  #02  pc 0000000000018080  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+156)
  #03  pc 0000000000017f34  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+60)
  #04  pc 00000000000f7670  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android18NativeMessageQueue8pollOnceEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjecti+48)
  #05  pc 00000000009df410  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce__JI+140)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (MessageQueue.java)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:323)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6682)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke! (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1534)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1424)
```

My app uses a large native library and we do separate builds for 32 and 64 bit builds. The 32 bit build does not show any crashes like this. Interestingly, all those crashes, except for one, come from different Samsung Galaxy devices. I have several Galaxy devices for testing, yet never experienced this crash here.

The app is using several AsyncTasks in Java and threads on the native side. I know this crash means that some operation is holding up the main thread but how can I figure out where this crash is coming from exactly and if it is indeed coming from my code? There are no user reports so I don't know what has happened before the crash. Any input is highly appreciated!

Comment: We're having the same problem exactly.